# Holding an object with 2 hands in animation

Tags: modeling, animation, rigging, bones

I'm trying to do an animation with a character which I rigged with Rigify. The character needs to hold a ball in a certain way and the ball needs to move like this: https://www.instagram.com/p/CBCUGgSHkgY/?igshid=1u1zdupnkeb89 . I've spent quite some time and managed to find Child Of Constraint and I managed to hold it onto one of the hands but I failed to do so with the other hand. I could animate the fingers and the hand frame by frame but I don't think that it's the efficient way. Do you have any ideas on how I can do it?

Comment: I haven't really gotten into Blender's bone system, but I saw this problem solved in another program by parenting the hand IK targets to the ball and using the ball to drive the hand positions...

Comment: @RonJensen Thanks, I'll try it as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved my problem. Instead of using "Child Of" constraint, I've used **IK** and **Copy Rotation constraints**. Firstly, I've added an armature to my ball mesh. 1 bone for the general ball movement and the other 2 child bones for the hand/arm targets. Then I've added **IK constraints** to the forearms with child bones selected as targets. (Do not forget to change the chain length to 2-3. Since I was using the Rigify rig model, I've used 3 as chain length.) And finally, I've added **Copy Rotation constraint** to the hands and I attached the child bones to them.

**For more information:** https://youtu.be/Jv1InLG58GI